# Which DLL files does Windows Explorer use?

Tags: windows, shell, dll, dllimport, windows-explorer

I need to know which libraries Windows Explorer uses (Windows Shell) for a project.  Yeah it obviously uses `shell32.dll` but what others?

Comment: Graphics library- gdi32.dll and user library- user32.dll

Comment: Is there something that it uses to control audio, I know about gdi and user, I use them a lot.  I have to know about audio and stuff too.

Comment: I believe that depends on audio driver..

Comment: No, Explorer recieves messages when you press a button or send out a message to change the audio, then it in turn adjusts the audio from what I understand....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to look what Explorer references.

Comment: Note that you can also use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and set the lower-pane view to “DLLs”.